# extract data from div tags with same name selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Hello I am scraping a data which has some info under its div tag like this :

```html
<div class="result-item-cell result-person-info">
info
info
</div>
<div class="result-item-cell result-person-info">
info
so on...
```

What I want is that all the data can be printed on the terminal.

**My code :**

```py
sun=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="result-item-cell result-person-info"]').text
print (sun)
driver.quit()
```

This code is kinda working only, when I use "element" and that only prints 1st div tag and closes

When I use "elements" I get a error saying :

> list index out of range

I also tried "find element by class name" but that didn't worked as it was saying not able to find the class name.

I don't understand what is wrong, someone can help me ?

Comment: The problem is that you are using `find_elementS` (plural) which returns a collection of elements and then using `.text` which can only be used on a single element. That's the reason for the `list index out of range` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could grab all the elemens with that specific class name into a list.
Then loop trough that list:

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('result-person-info')
for element in elems:
    print(element)
```

Comment: This isn't really going to do anything useful because you are printing the WebElement which is going to be some GUID. You should be printing `element.text`.

Comment: I agree. But since he was justing printing the element in his original post, I did the same.

Comment: He wasn't printing the element, he was printing `.text`... he just happened to be printing `.text` on a collection which resulted in the error message.

Comment: You are right. It was the width of my screen which wasn't showing it right. That's why I didn't notice.